# Quoting: loop over ssh-accounts, call psql on remote server

Tags: shell, quoting

This works in the human brain, but the shell misses quoting:

```
for h in a b; do ssh $h psql -tAc "select * from mytab where mycol='x'"; done
```

How to quote this one liner without loosing readability?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes. Think of them as layers of wrapping, in a game of pass the parcel. Each shell unwraps a 'layer'.

So:

```
echo "this ; is a semicolon"
```

But if you wanted to run that via ssh:

```
ssh $user@$host echo "this ; is a semicolon"
```

The *ssh* would unwrap the first layer of the package - sending:

```
echo this ; is a semicolon
```

Which would break, because semicolons are interpreted by the shell.

So to do this, you need to escape the quotes first - so ssh can 'unwrap' one layer safely:

```
ssh $user@$host echo "\"this ; is a semicolon\""
```

ssh will thus strip the 'outer'layer, and the 'escape' and pass through:

```
echo "this ; is a semicolon"
```

This will be what you need to do for your one liner. As for not losing readability - easier said than done I'm afraid, as escapes and quote nesting do inevitably get messy.

About the best I can offer is using a variable to encapsulate your SQL statement, so that it's at least clear that you're sending an 'encapsulated statement:

```
THING_TO_ECHO='"this ; is a semicolon"'; ssh $user@host echo $THING_TO_ECHO
```

Comment: I am missing the `for` loop in your answer.